# Very Slow Accumulate of random time segments

Tags: date-and-time, timing, list-manipulation

Even for short list (15 elem) of **random** time segments of **DateObjects**, `Accumulate` consumes unexpectedly long times. But, when time segments are not random, or are Accumulated as a `Quantity`, prior adding to DateObject (conversion to DateObject), there are no such long computation long times. For list of length few dozens computation time approaches infinity. Eg.

Delta times before accumulation:

```
dtimqr = Quantity[IntegerPart[RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[9, 0.1], 15]*86400], "Seconds"];
dtimq = Quantity[Table[135000, 15], "Seconds"];
```

Accumulation as a DateObjects:

```
{Timing[ftimr = Accumulate@({FromUnixTime[0]}~Join~dtimqr);], 
 Timing[ftim = Accumulate@({FromUnixTime[0]}~Join~dtimq);]}
(* {{14.0625, Null}, {0.0625, Null}} *)

{Timing[ftimrP=FromUnixTime[0]+Accumulate@({Quantity[0, "Seconds"]}~Join~dtimqr);],
 Timing[ftimP=FromUnixTime[0]+Accumulate@({Quantity[0, "Seconds"]}~Join~dtimq);]}
(* {{0.0625, Null}, {0.046875, Null}} *)
```

Is there reasonable explanation for such a long computation time when Accumulating lists with random dateObjects, as short as 15 elements. ?

Comment: There's a lot of overhead involved in carrying around and manipulating `DateObject[]`s. I would suggest keeping things in `UnixTime[]` or `AbsoluteTime[]`, and convert to explicit dates only when you need to display them.

Comment: @J.M. but why when DateObjects are random, only? I have few thousands objects from TimeSeries data, and if this is the case, this will complicate my code a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use *Date Operations* functions as found in the [Date & Time](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DateAndTime.html) guide to operate on [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html)s.  For example, you may use [`DatePlus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatePlus.html) with [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html).

```
SeedRandom[978];
dtimqr = Quantity[
   IntegerPart[RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[9, 0.1], 15]*86400], 
   "Seconds"];
```

Compare `DatePlus`

```
AbsoluteTiming[FoldList[DatePlus[##] &, FromUnixTime@0, dtimqr];]
```

> ```
> {0.00311076, Null}
> ```

to [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html)

```
AbsoluteTiming[Accumulate@({FromUnixTime[0]}~Join~dtimqr);]
```

> ```
> {9.56173, Null}
> ```

Hope this helps.